# theme and mode path infer issue with ace.js and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Sorry, the question unfortunately hasn't got much detail as I am not sure what exactly is required to explain the issue. To start with, I am trying to use `ng2-ace-editor` in my `Angular` application. My setup is not standard though. Details are in this other related problem - [application can't find a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176763/application-cant-find-a-js-file)

In summary, if I explicitly include `ace.js` in my top level `html` then things work. But I don't want to do that as I want to use only the bundles created by `Angular`. But if I use only the bundles then I get the following error when I run the application -

```
ace.js:1 Unable to infer path to ace from script src, use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver
f @ ace.js:1
t.loadModule @ ace.js:1
setTheme @ ace.js:1
setTheme @ ace.js:1
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.setTheme @ component.js:117
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.init @ component.js:48
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.ngOnInit @ component.js:40
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:9250
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:10514
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:10476
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:11109
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:11069
eval @ NewPracticeQuestionComponent.html:188
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:11061
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10458
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:10662
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10459
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11351
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:11029
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:8845
(anonymous) @ core.js:4581
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4581
(anonymous) @ core.js:4473
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3824
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3738
next @ core.js:4473
schedulerFn @ core.js:3555
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:209
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:147
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3539
checkStable @ core.js:3793
onHasTask @ core.js:3837
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
Show 26 more frames
ace.js:1 GET http://localhost:9000/theme-monokai.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
t.loadScript @ ace.js:1
t.loadModule @ ace.js:1
setTheme @ ace.js:1
setTheme @ ace.js:1
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.setTheme @ component.js:117
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.init @ component.js:48
push../node_modules/ng2-ace-editor/src/component.js.AceEditorComponent.ngOnInit @ component.js:40
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:9250
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:10514
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:10476
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:11109
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:11069
eval @ NewPracticeQuestionComponent.html:188
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:11061
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10458
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:10662
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10459
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callViewAction @ core.js:10699
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10641
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10464
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11351
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:11029
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:8845
(anonymous) @ core.js:4581
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4581
(anonymous) @ core.js:4473
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3824
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3738
next @ core.js:4473
schedulerFn @ core.js:3555
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:209
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:147
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:55
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3539
checkStable @ core.js:3793
onHasTask @ core.js:3837
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
Show 26 more frames
414ede0a-7ac6-4556-a68b-bfcd8c991283:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:9000/worker-javascript.js' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:9000/414ede0a-7ac6-4556-a68b-bfcd8c991283:1:1
```

Further analysis shows that the error is thrown from the following piece of code in `ace.js`.

```
exports.loadModule = function(moduleName, onLoad) {
    var module, moduleType;
    if (Array.isArray(moduleName)) {
        moduleType = moduleName[0];
        moduleName = moduleName[1];
    }

    try {
        module = require(moduleName);
    } catch (e) {}
    if (module && !exports.$loading[moduleName])
        return onLoad && onLoad(module);

    if (!exports.$loading[moduleName])
        exports.$loading[moduleName] = [];

    exports.$loading[moduleName].push(onLoad);

    if (exports.$loading[moduleName].length > 1)
        return;

    var afterLoad = function() {
        require([moduleName], function(module) {
            exports._emit("load.module", {name: moduleName, module: module});
            var listeners = exports.$loading[moduleName];
            exports.$loading[moduleName] = null;
            listeners.forEach(function(onLoad) {
                onLoad && onLoad(module);
            });
        });
    };

    if (!exports.get("packaged"))
        return afterLoad();

    net.loadScript(exports.moduleUrl(moduleName, moduleType), afterLoad);
    reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured();
};

var reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured = function() {
    if (
        !options.basePath && !options.workerPath 
        && !options.modePath && !options.themePath
        && !Object.keys(options.$moduleUrls).length
    ) {
        console.error(
            "Unable to infer path to ace from script src,",
            "use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes",
            "or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver"
        );
        reportErrorIfPathIsNotConfigured = function() {};
    }
};
```

What is causing the issue? I suppose `Angular` uses `webpack`. What is this `ace/webpack-resolver` thing? How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally was able to make my code work. My setup is different.

The reason adding `script` tag explicitly made my code work is because `By default ace detcts the url for dynamic loading by finding the script node for ace.js. This doesn't work if ace.js is not loaded with a separate script tag, and in this case it is required to set url explicitely` (https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto). As I am loading `modes` and `themes` without using `script`, I had to use `basePath` etc. (see answer further).

I build my `Angular` application and the it is served from my `Play` server. The `angular` build is stored in `Play`'s `/public/ui` folder. The requests should be in format `/assets/ui/..` which gets mapped to `/public/ui/...` due to a rule in Play routes file

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

When I ran the code, I got error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:9000/worker-javascript.js' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:9000/3df21e42-fecb-4026-8bd6-f2b0d1d0540a:1:1
Earlier, I also got error `Unable to infer path to ace from script src, use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver`
```

It seems `ng-ace-editor` imports `.js` scripts (theme, mode, worker) based on the theme and mode of the editor. The theme and mode `.js` files can be included in `scripts.js` but some `worker-.js` files can't be (I don't know why, maybe because worker ones are loaded dynamically using `importScript`).

The scripts section in `Angular.json` is (this will all get bundled in `scripts.js` in Angular's final bundle)

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-eclipse.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-monokai.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/mode-html.js"
            ]]
```

To include `worker-.js` files, I added this rule because it seems `angular-cli` can't load from `node_modules`. So I had to copy the files from node modules to root of my `ui` build - How to include assets from node_modules in angular cli project

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
```

When I executed the code, I found error that `http://localhost:9000/worker-javascript.js can't be loaded`. I realised that my files are loaded in `/assets/ui/` path and not in the server's root directory. So I set `ace.js`'s `basepath` to `/assets/ui` in the component's `.ts` file

```
import * as ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';
    ace.config.set('basePath', '/assets/ui/');
    ace.config.set('modePath', '');
    ace.config.set('themePath', '');
```

In summary `basePath` seem to be what is used to load scripts dynamically (eg worker scripts). `modePath` and `themePath` are `/` as the mode and theme scripts are bundled in `scripts.js` and my `index.html` correctly loaded `scripts.js` using `<script>` tag and are available at root level need to copy worker-.js files outside node_modules as angular_cli can't copy assets from node_modules